# Migration site choice dropdown completely out of place on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, close-dialog

Default mobile site:

[image: default mobile site]

(once I type enough that "coffee" is the only thing that shows up, I can't see it anywhere - maybe it's under the box or something)

Desktop site on mobile:

[image]

This is chrome 54.0.284042 on Android 7.0.

I know this is kind of a corner case, and it's not impossible to use, but it's pretty awkward!

Comment: The reason is missing CSS class, that on the full site forcing size of 58x58 pixels of the sites icons. The actual size is 158x158 so on mobile theme, where nothing resizing it, it's way too big to fit.